# Feauterd image meta box not showing up

Tags: editor, images, post-editor, post-thumbnails

I Updated my wordpress from **4.6 to 4.7.2** last night and now i can see that in the post editor in admin panel there is no meta box for selecting the featured images.
I also did some editing on the default different image size generation in the settings in here:

[image]

I set the meduim and large to 0.
I also commented out all my **add_image_size()** functions in my **function.php** file in my custom theme.

I would highly appreciate some help. i'm stuck

Comment: and it's not in screen options section

Answer (score 1):

I find the problem i had accidentally deleted this function in my functions.php file in the theme directory.

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');